# Java find common elements in a collection

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, collections

I need to find common elements in a collection of arrays using

```
public Comparable[] findCommonElements(Object[] collection)
```

as the signature of my algorithm, it should accept a collection of arrays (of varying length and of any type) as input, and be no greater than O(knlogn).

I want to do a quick sort (??) of the arrays then do a binary search for the common elements. This should put me right at O(knlogn), but I'm not 100% sure about efficiency.

I'm lost on how to get the binary search to search the collections and then print the common elements. I am aware I cannot call common from a static method, but I left it to give an idea of what I tried. I am aware my time would be better spent learning how to use array lists and hash sets, but I am supposed to use concepts already covered, and these have not been.

### Code:

```
public class CommonElements2<T extends Comparable<T>>
{
   Comparable[] tempArr;
   Comparable[] queryArray;
   Comparable[] common = new Comparable[queryArray.length];
   int counter = 0;
/* 
sort algorithm goes here
*/   
   public Comparable[] findCommonElements(Object[] collections)
   {
      queryArray = ((Comparable[])collections[0]);
      boolean found = false;

      for(int x = 0; x < queryArray.length; ++x)
      {
         for(int y = 1; y < collections.length; ++y)
         {
            tempArr = (Comparable[])collections[y];
            found = binarySearch(tempArr, 0, tempArr.length, queryArray[x]);

            if(!found)
            {
               break;
            }
            if(found)
            {
               common[counter] = queryArray[x];
               ++counter;
            }  
         } //end y for loop
      } // end x for loop
      return common;      
   } // end findCommonElements

   public boolean binarySearch(Comparable[] arr, int first, int last, Object searchItem)
   {
      boolean found;
      int mid = (first + (last - first)) /2;

      if(first > last)
         return false;

      int value = ((Comparable)searchItem).compareTo(arr[mid]);

      if(value < 0)
         value = -1;

      switch(value)
      {
         case 0:
            found = true;
            break;
         case -1:
            found = binarySearch(arr, first, mid - 1, searchItem);
            break;
         default:
            found = binarySearch(arr, mid + 1, last, searchItem);
            break;
      }
      return found;
   } //end bianry search

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
        Object [] collections = new Object[4];
        collections[0] = new Integer[]{3, 4, 9, 8, 12, 15, 7, 13};
    collections[1] = new Integer[]{15,24,50,12,3,9};
    collections[2] = new Integer[]{78,65,24,13,9,3,12};
    collections[3] = new Integer[]{15,78,14,3,2,9,44,12};

        CommonElements2<Integer> one = new CommonElements2<Integer>();
        System.out.println(one.findCommonElements(collections));

   }
} // end class
```

Thank you for any help and input!

Comment: That method declaration came up from you or that came directly from your assignment?

Comment: Assignment requires it

Comment: I mean if your teacher/professor defined `public Comparable[] findCommonElements(Object[] collection)` as the method signature or if this was your idea.

Comment: Yes, the instructor said it has to be used. From the assignment instructions: In your CommonElements class, encapsulate your algorithm within a method called findCommonElements, that has the following signature:
 public Comparable[] findCommonElements(Object[] collection). 
The argument to this method, collection, will be the set of k arrays discussed earlier. Each array will be represented as an array of objects of type Comparable.

Comment: You're assuming the array is already sorted. If is not, then you could sort it using [`Collections#sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object[])) which already has a O(nlogn) time. Then, since the elements are already sorted, you can just go through the array and spot the common elements in it by comparing the elements in pairs (thus saving the time consumed by the binary search).

Comment: I do intend to write a sort algorithm, but got frustrated and figured I'd come back to it when I had the finding of the common elements part figured out. What would you use to compare elements in pairs?

Comment: Something like `if (yourArray[i] == yourArray[i-1])`, assuming `0 < i < yourArray.length` .

Comment: If I am understanding that correctly, it sounds like it would search within one array for common elements not within all of the arrays?

Comment: First find the common elements in an array and store them in a single array. Do this for all the arrays and store them in the same collection. Then, repeat this algorithm in your array of common elements.

Comment: What if there are none?
`collections[0]{1, 2, 3};
collections[1]{2, 3, 5, 7};
collections[2]{0, 2, 3, 7};`
So 2 and 3 are the common elements, but they don't repeat within a single array.

Comment: And you cannot use a `Set`, right?

Comment: If you don't have any memory restriction, then you could store every element of each array inside a big giant array, then sort it (which has a time of O(knlogn)) and do a search by comparing elements next to each other.

Comment: I was thinking about that. If I have 4 arrays for example, use merge sort on 3 and keep one as a query array. Then search the merged array for the elements in the query array, counting the matches as it goes. If it matches the number of arrays put it into a new commonElement array. Would that work?

Comment: When you say *use merge sort on 3 of them* you mean use merge sort per array or use merge sort between them and generate a new bigger array?

Comment: Merge 3 into one big array. And if element [0] from array[1] shows up in the big array 3 times, put it into the commonElements arrays.

Comment: Yes, that may do it. But, for example, you have `collections[0]{0, 0, 0}; collections[1]{1, 1, 1, 1}; collections[2]{1, 1, 1, 1}; collections[3]{1, 1};` and you merge from `collections[1]` to `collections[3]` then you will get an array filled with `1`s and searching `0` will always be false =\

Comment: That would be good for it to be false since it is not in all 4 arrays. In that case thee would be no common elements.

Comment: So you're finding only elements common to all arrays! Silly me! Haha. Ok, taking the example from my last comment, if you merge `collections[0]` to `collections[3]` and use `collections[4]` as your query array, you will spot `1` but it is not in all the arrays.

Comment: What about this: 1. Sorting all the arrays separately O(knlogn). 2. Take two arrays A1 and A2 from the array of arrays. 3. Navigate through every item of A1 and search if the element is in A2 using binary search O(nlogn). 3. Store the common elements from A1 and A2 into array B. 4. Take another array from the arrays of arrays as A1, use array B as A2. 5. Go to step 3 and repeat the process until you have used all the arrays in your array of arrays O(knlogn).

Comment: Well collections [0] through collections[2] and collections[3] would be the 4th and query array. I do realize that the duplicate numbers in one array is a problem that needs solving, but I'd like to try to get enough together to have it handle situations without duplications.
Would merging all but one array be a good way to go? Or should I stick with a binary search of multiple arrays?

Comment: I posted another comment explaining an idea above.

Comment: I think that was what I was trying to do in my code above... or that was my intent... sort of. I'm kind of lost on how to take the collections that have values assigned in `main` and actually get the `findCommonElements`to use them.

Comment: In my idea, `queryArray` initial value will be the first array of your array of arrays, but then on every iteration it will become the common elements that are the result of every comparison between arrays. I'll post it as an answer and provide a pseudocode for it (since the implementation is up to you, otherwise I would end up doing the homework :) ).

Comment: No, no I'm definitely not asking for it to be done for me. Probably a dumb question, but is a collection an array of arrays?
In your concept, what happens if the element is common in A1 and A2 (it has gone to the array B), but it is not in A3?

Comment: A collection is a class that works as a container of objects. For example, a `List`, a `Set`, a `Map`, a tree, etc. For example: `List<String>` is a list (`ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, etc) that holds `String` objects, `Set<Integer>` is a set (`HashSet`, `TreeSet`, etc) that holds a set of `Integer` objects, and on. Note that a collection can contain other collections e.g. `List<Set<Integer>>`. You can find more info here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/intro/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment, here's an algorithm that can fulfill your work:

1. Sorting all the arrays separately O(knlogn).
2. Take two arrays A1 and A2 from the array of arrays.
3. Navigate through every item of A1 and search if the element is in A2 using binary search O(nlogn).
4. Store the common elements from A1 and A2 into array B.
5. Take another array from the arrays of arrays as A2, use array B as A1.
6. Go to step 3 and repeat the process until you have used all the arrays in your array of arrays O(knlogn).

Here's a pseudocode of the proposed algorithm (looks like Java code but **is not** Java code at all):

```
public Comparable[] findCommonElements(Object[] collections) {
    //1.
    for each collection in collections
        Comparable[] compCollection = (Comparable[])collection
        sort(compCollection)
    end for
    //2.
    Comparable[] a1 = (Comparable[])collections[0]
    //assume MAX is a really high value like 10000
    //the best value for MAX would be the max length of the arrays in collections
    Comparable[] b = new Comparable[MAX]
    int bSize = 0
    //6.
    for i = 1 to collections.length - 1
        //5.
        Comparable[] a2 = (Comparable[])collections[i]
        //3.
        for each Comparable comp in a1
            int index = binarySearch(comp, a2)
            if index >= 0 then
                //4.
                add a2[index] into b
                bSize = bSize + 1
            end if
        end for
        //5.
        a1 = b
        b = new Comparable[MAX]
        bSize = 0
    end for
    return b
}
```